# How to refresh two form in one button at the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have created two form in one page each form having  it's own button . when I click a first form button should refresh both form at the same time.

my first form is look like this

```
<form id="search_form" method="post" action="do_searchID.php"> 
        <label>Enter Employee Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="emp_id" id="emp_id">
        <button type="submit" name="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

my second form is look like this at the same page

```
<form method="post" action="do_searchID.php">
<label>Full Name</label>
<input type="text"  id="full_name" value="">
<button type="submit" name="submit_update">Update Now </button>
</form>
```

from this how can write jquery to do above task. Please help me I have no idea by doing this task I have to retrieve data's from database.

Comment: you need to use `$.ajax()`http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: you want to submit both forms or rest (clear) both forms on one button click ?

Comment: @coolguy, same question...!!

Comment: why do you need to create 2 forms in on page if u want to trigger them at once , just create one .

Comment: You can use JQuery to clear the form values on both the forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using ajax. I think you are trying to search employee with employee id and show employee name in second form. For that here is ajax code

```
$(function()){
var emp_id = $('#emp_id').val();
$.ajax({
          url: filename.php,
          data: {'emp_id':emp_id},
          dataType: 'json',
          method:'POST',
            success:function (data)
            {
                var emp_name = data.empname;
                /* If its receiving json in data then parse like JSON.parse(data). Then get employee name*/
                $("#fullname").val('emp_name');
            }
        });
});
```

In php you can get the emp_id by $_POST['emp_id'] and search the employee name by emp_id and return employee name.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#SearchButton").click(function(){
     // Trigger your submit of both form
     $("#search_form,#ID_form_2").submit();
})
```

You can use above code. if you have want this to be done on first submit button call.

FORM1

```
<form id="search_form" method="post" action="do_searchID.php"> 
    <label>Enter Employee Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="emp_id" id="emp_id">
    <button type="submit" id='SearchButton' name="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

FORM2

```
<form method="post" id='ID_form_2' action="do_searchID.php">
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text"  id="full_name" value="">
    <button type="submit" name="submit_update">Update Now </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use a common class to all fields you want to refresh.. and create a function which do that.

Like this.

```
  function refreshForm()
   {
   $(".commonClass").val('');
   }
```

thats it.